# Support of a faithful representation

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Any representation $\pi:A\to B(H)$ is uniquely extended to a $w^*$-continuous representation $\tilde{\pi}:A^{**}\to B(H)$.

Q: I am looking for an example of  a faithful representation $\pi$ such that $\tilde{\pi}$ is no longer faithful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most reasonable cases $\tilde{\pi}$ is not faithful.

Consider the diagonal embedding $\pi\colon \ell_\infty \to B(\ell_2)$ with respect to any orthonormal basis. Certainly there is no faithful representation $\ell_\infty^{**}\to B(\ell_2)$ as $\ell_\infty^{**}$ is not $\sigma$-finite. Consequently, $\tilde{\pi}$ is not faithful.

This can be generalised to the setting where $A$ acts on a separable Hilbert space and contains an element with uncountable spectrum.

Comment: Dear Tomek Kania, this question may be asked for the left kernel of positive  linear functional. I mean that, let $\phi$ be a positive linear functional on a C*-algebra $A$ and let $\tilde{\phi}$ be its unique $w^*$-continuous extension on the second dual $A^{**}$. The left kernel of $\phi$, denoted by $N_{\phi}$, is $\{x\in A: \phi(x^*x)=0\}$ and $N_{\tilde{\phi}}=\{x\in A^{**}:\tilde{\phi}(x^*x)=0\}$. Does there exist an example of a non-faithful positive linear functional $\phi$ such that $N_{\tilde{\phi}}$ is not the weak-star closure of $N_{\phi}$?